# JQuery Form Plugin, can't receive data in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, plugins

I'm using [JQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for AJAX file uploader.

The (html) form is **created dynamically**, and looks like this:

```
<form id="formUpload" action="fileReceiver.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>
```

Because, the form is created dynamically, I'm using jquery on(). I also **need to send a few variables**, I'm using [data options](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object) from the plugin.

The Javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form#formUpload", function() {
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        data: { someVariable : 'someValue' },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 
});
```

I think the form is binded correctly, I could call/alert something from the ajaxForm (jquery form plugin) function through beforeSend or Success options.

Now, the problem is the PHP couldn't get the data I posted in the Javascript.

My PHP is simple like this:

```
<?php
   echo $_POST["someVariable"];
?>
```

It gives me error "**Notice: Undefined index**: someVariable blah blah blah"

Any advice? Thx :)

Comment: did you try setting `type` to `POST` ? It should any way consider form's method set in `form` tag but try setting manually.

Comment: and why do you need `$(document) submit` event ?

Comment: Have you looked at the request / response in a the browser's developer tools to see what, if anything, is being posted? You may not be sending anything to PHP for it to see in the $_POST array.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: @phobos : yes, in the form and in the option parameters.

Comment: @phobos: because the form is created dynamically, I need to use the parent of the form as some kind of scope, isn't it? so Document or Body.

Comment: @Jay: yep, the file is uploaded (checked), but there is no request at my browser's Firebug. Any idea why?

Comment: @rooivalk just answered your question. see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some variables in hidden input inside form

```
<input type="hidden" name="someVariable" value="someValue">
```

and remove $(document).on("submit",... event

You can try

```
var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "someVariable").val("someValue");
$('#formUpload').append($(input));
```

this links may help you

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/progress2.html

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/file-echo2.php.txt

Comment: I'm trying to avoid input type hidden, also the variables I need are in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case your form is being added dynamically then you'd have to use `DOMNodeInserted` event instead of `submit`. That way, whenever there's some addition in DOM your form will be attached to form plugin.

You can replace your function with following --

```
    $(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", "form#formUpload", function() {
        $(this).ajaxForm({
            data: { someVariable : 'someValue' },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                // do something 
            }
        });
    });
```

But remember, using `DOMNodeInserted` event will fire that method whenever there's addition of any kind into DOM. So just put what is essential ( in this case form plugin init for `#formUpload` ) .

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate if you already added the jQuery Form Plugin...

```
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Your syntax is definitely correct according to http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object